# Jsoup, MySQL: How to prevent doubleEntries in database via JavaCode

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, jsoup, html-parser

I'm trying to extract data and write it directly in a database I created by 
phpmyadmin (wampServer). The data is growing each day and I must keep it 
uptoday, so I will run my prorammcode in a period of some days. And now my 
problem: how can I prevent identically entries? I tried it by names, ID, and 
URL. The problem is, that some data have the same ID. By using names it throw 
Syntax-exeption cause of the SQL-statements (a lot of the names have letters 
like: ";", """, "\", "`", ":", which makes it rather difficult) and when I use 
URL no errors will be thrown, but then I have a lot of double-entries. 
Not all data, that exist already gets into the database, but I can only block a few of them.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my programmCode:

```
package htmlParser;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import data.DatenBank_Steam_Spiele;
import data.Spiel;

public class Steam_GameID_Links
{
    public ArrayList<Spiel> spiele;
    public final static String DELIMITER = "Trennzeichen";
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306    /Steam_Spiele";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    Steam_GameID_Links wc = new Steam_GameID_Links();
    try
    {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase, "root", "");
        System.out.println("Verbindung erfogreich hergestellt");

        String url = "http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=_ASC&category1=998&page=1";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements howMuchPages = document.select(".search_pagination_right");
        String[] stuff = howMuchPages.text().split(" ");
        String tmp = stuff[4].replace(" ", "").replace(".", "");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(tmp.charAt(i)))
            {
                sb.append(tmp.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        String last = sb.toString().trim();;
        int lastPages = Integer.parseInt(last);
        int counter = 0;
        wc.spiele = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < lastPages + 1; i++)

        {
            System.out.println("______________________ SpieleAngebot Seite " + i + " von insgesamt " + lastPages
                    + " Seiten.");
            url = "http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=_ASC&category1=998&page=" + i;
            // ACHTUNG: ohne timeout(0) kann der AusleseProzess VORHER abbrechen (dauert zu lange)
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
            // waehlt zunaechst den ElternKnoten: <div id="search_result_container">
            Element parentNode = document.getElementById("search_result_container");
            Elements childNodes = parentNode.getElementsByAttribute("data-ds-appid");
            // FUNZT (releasedates)
            Elements releasedates = document.select("div.col.search_released.responsive_secondrow");
            Elements prices = document.select("div.col.search_price.responsive_secondrow");
            for(int j = 0; j < releasedates.size(); j++)
            {
                String name = childNodes.get(j).getElementsByClass("title").text();
                String id = childNodes.get(j).attr("data-ds-appid");
                int ID = Integer.parseInt(id);
                String href = childNodes.get(j).attr("href");
                String releaseDate = releasedates.get(j).text();
                String priceAll = prices.get(j).text();
                String[] getPrice = priceAll.split(" ");
                String price = getPrice[getPrice.length - 1];
                // Liste befuellen WICHTIG fuer Textfile!!
                wc.spiele.add(new Spiel(name, ID, href, price, releaseDate));

                //check if the game is already in database
                String search = "SELECT * FROM spiel WHERE URL LIKE \"" + href + "\"";
                Statement checkIfAlreadyThere = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = checkIfAlreadyThere.executeQuery(search);
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("Game already in database");
                }
                else
                {
                    String insert = "INSERT INTO spiel (NAME, ID, URL, VERÖFFENTLICHT, PREIS)"
                            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(2, ID);
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, href);
                    preparedStatement.setString(4, releaseDate);
                    if(price.equals("Play") || price.equals("Free"))
                    {
                        price = "kostenlos";
                    }
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, price);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Anzahl Spiele: " + counter);

        for(Spiel out : wc.spiele)
        {
            wc.writeSpielNameIDLink("Spiel:" + out.getName() + DELIMITER + "ID:" + out.getID() + DELIMITER
                    + "SpieleLink:" + out.getLink() + DELIMITER + "veröffentlicht:" + out.getReleaseDate()
                    + DELIMITER + "Preis:" + out.getPrice() + "\n \n");
        }
        wc.writeSpielNameIDLink("\n \n Anzahl Spiele: " + counter);
        Steam_Sales_Per_Game spG = new Steam_Sales_Per_Game();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the very unique identifier of a game. You should have a look if steam provides a very unique id for games and use this id as identifier for a game.
When I check the steam link of your url in code I can see an app ID per listed entry.
The app id exists as tag-attribute in the top link `<a>` of a game entry (href after /app/ part)

[image]

EDIT: the id is unique in href attribute

Comment: that is the ID I mentioned, but its unfortuanately NOT unique (I know it makes no sense, but its true). For exampel:
 Fallout 3: NAME1= "Fallout: New Vegas" NAME2 ="Fallout: New Vegas Ultimate Edition" BUT: they have both the same ID = 22380!

otherwise things wouldn't be a big problem, if the ID (like usually) were unique  :-(

Comment: The only REAL unique Thing I have found is the name, but then I run always into that SQL-Sytax error, cause of some stupid names of games^^

Comment: Take the id from the href attribute. Just split it. After the '.../app/'-String the id is unique, even for fallout new vegas and the ultimate edition of new vegas.

Comment: Oh, you're right, thanks a lot. I haven't recognized this. Thanks.

Comment: Try to separate the `ID` from the href and convert it to `int`. Create a new column for id or use the existing one. Further I suggest you cleanup your code. [single responsibilty principle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-Responsibility-Prinzip)

Comment: Please open a new issue. Don't write answers which are actually new issues/topics.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code-extract to check whether a game is already in the database:

```
String search = "SELECT * FROM spiel WHERE URL LIKE \"" + href + "\"";
Statement checkIfAlreadyThere = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = checkIfAlreadyThere.executeQuery(search);
if(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println("Game already in database");
 }
 else
  {
      << pseudoCode: insert game into database >>>
  }
```

as mentioned bevore checking the URL causes no problems but isn't effective, using NAME (which will be the best solution cause its really unique) causes Syntax error.
Maybe there is a better way to create that SQL-Statment?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it, thanks to @Erik B from B, you gave me the right hint.
And here is my solution code -extract:

```
String href = childNodes.get(j).attr("href");
String cutFirstpart = href.replaceAll("http://store.steampowered.com/app/", "");
String[] hrefSplit = cutFirstpart.split("/");
String uniqueID = hrefSplit[0];
int ID = Integer.parseInt(uniqueID);
String releaseDate = releasedates.get(j).text();
String priceAll = prices.get(j).text();
String[] getPrice = priceAll.split(" ");
String price = getPrice[getPrice.length - 1];
//check if the game is already in database
String search = "SELECT * FROM spiel WHERE ID LIKE \"" + ID + "\"";
Statement checkIfAlreadyThere = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = checkIfAlreadyThere.executeQuery(search);
if(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println("Game already in database");
}
else
{
      << insert NEW data into database >>>>
}
```